# Handling subscription/unsubscription to a ton of events with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

In my current project, i'm dealing with firebase websocket subscriptions. Different components can subscribe to different data, e.g. in a list of items every `ListItem` component subscribes to a websocket "event" for that specific item by dispatching a `SUBSCRIBE` action in `componentDidMount` and unsubscribes by dispatching an `UNSUBSCRIBE` action in `componentWillUnmount`.

My sagas look like this:

```
const subscriptions = {}

export function * subscribeLoop () {
  while (true) {
    const { path } = yield take(SUBSCRIBE)
    subscriptions[path] = yield fork(subscription, path)
  }
}

export function * unsubscribeLoop () {
  while (true) {
    const { path } = yield take(UNSUBSCRIBE)
    yield cancel(subscriptions[path])
  }
}

export function * subscription (path) {
  let ref

  try {
    const updateChannel = channel()

    ref = api.child(path)
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
      updateChannel.put(snapshot.val())
    })

    while (true) {
      const data = yield take(updateChannel)
      yield put(handleUpdate(path, data))
    }
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      ref.off()
      ref = null
    }
  }
}
```

I assume this is not the right way to deal with this - it is indeed rather slow on a list of 500 items.

**How can i optimize the performance?**

- Do i even need to fork?
- Should i introduce some kind of delay to give the thread some space to handle other things?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Should i introduce some kind of delay to give the thread some space > to handle other things?

First of all it is necessary to remember that use of redux saga and effects like fork actually doesn't create any threads which would be twisted in the infinite loops. It is only syntactic sugar for the organization of a chain of callbacks as the yield operator provides object passing in both sides. From this point of view a question of forced delays doesn't make a sense - as thread and doesn't exist.

> Do i even need to fork?

In case of due skill it is possible to do generally without set of fork of calls, and to do everything in one root saga. The idea is in making a subscription with a callback function in the current lexical area on websocket, and to expect obtaining messages in the pseudo-infinite loop on the basis of delayed promise.

Conceptually the code can look approximately so:

```
const subscribers = new Map()

function * webSocketLoop() {
  let resolver = null
  let promise = new Promise(resolve => (resolver = resolve))
  let message = null;

  websocket.on('message', (payload) => {
    message = Object.assign({}, payload)
    resolver()
    promise = promise.then(() => new Promise(resolve => (resolver = resolve)))
  })

  while(true) {
    yield call(() => promise)
    const type = message.type
    const handlers = subscribers.get(type) || []
    handlers.forEach(func => func(message))
  }
}

export function * mainSaga () {
  yield takeEvery(SUBSCRIBE, subscribe)
  yield takeEvery(UNSUBSCRIBE, unsubscribe)
  yield fork(webSocketLoop)
}
```